# Problem with facebook login in flutter ios app

Tags: flutter, dart, facebook-login

Hello I have this error when trying to add Facebook login to my flutter app . and I try to install facebook SDK in many ways like  download and cocoapods . in in all way I have the same error

```
'../AppEvents/Internal/ViewHierarchy/FBSDKViewHierarchy.h' file not found
```

[image]

Comment: which pub you're using?

Comment: I think you haven't followed flutter_facebook_login plugin integration. Please Read [flutter_facebook_login_ReadMe](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login) plugin. If you still not get it , then let me know.

Comment: Sure . i followed flutter_facebook_login plugin integration and facebook developer<https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/> steps

Comment: @HarithALAny Any update?